# Interfaz List con distintas instanciaciones

Tags: java, poo, arraylist, lista

¿Cuál es la diferencia, ventajas, desventajas entre?:

1. `List a=new ArrayList();\\suponiendo que introducire numeros enteros`
2. `ArrayList a=new ArrayList(); \\suponiendo que introducire numeros enteros`
3. `ArrayList<Integer> a=new ArrayList<Integer>();`
4. `List <Integer> a=new ArrayList<Integer>();`

¿O son equivalentes todas ellas?

Nota: en lugar de `ArrayList` pudo tambien haber sido `LinkedList` o algún otro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La diferencia radica en qué es cada cosa:

- [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) es una interfaz (que extiende la interfaz `Collection`)
- [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) es una clase (que implementa la interfaz `List`)

Aunque todas las opciones que especificas funcionarán correctamente, usar la interfaz `List` tiene ventajas sobre usar la clase implementada `ArrayList` porque podrías beneficiarte del [polimorfismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo_(inform%C3%A1tica)) en programación orientada a objetos.

Por ejemplo, si luego más adelante en tu proyecto ves que necesitas cambiar la implementación, si has definido tu variable como `List` no deberías tener mucho problema en cambiar de `ArrayList` a otro tipo de clase que implemente la interfaz `List` (`LinkedList` por ejemplo). Por eso las opciones 1 y 4 pueden  ser más ventajosas.

Y ahora, definir el [parámetro de tipo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5) de la lista (opciones 3 y 4) o no definirlo (opciones 1 y 2)... va a depender de lo que quieras hacer. Si lo defines, entonces se van a validar los tipos en tiempo de compilación, lo cual puede ayudarte a encontrar errores, pero te va a dar menos flexibilidad luego.

Como parece que tienes claro que vas a usar `Integer` y no otros, entonces quizás te conviene más definir el tipo (opción 4), porque hará el código más fácil de mantener y depurar.

Comment: En lugar de trabajar con enteros, pudo haber sido `String` o incluso algo de tipo `class`.La opción 4 aun sera la mas ideal?

Comment: @Michelle yo lo cambiaría la 4 a una opción 3: `List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();`. Esta es la opción preferida puesto que, en tiempo de compilación, indicas que solo se pueden agregar instancias de `Integer` a la lista, así otros desarrolladores también pueden entender que esa lista solo puede llevar `Integer` y no otro tipo de datos. Similar sería si necesitas `List<String>` o `List<AlgunaClaseParticular>` como `List<Persona>` o `List<Producto>`.

Comment: Que sea un `String`, un `Integer` o una clase propia no debería ser un problema y debería funcionar igual. La idea es que al especificar un tipo, cuando se compile, se va a validar que se esté usando ese tipo, lo cual te puede ahorrar problemas. El concepto de ideal es relativo a las necesidades del proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

En principio son todas equivalentes, es decir, la diferencia entre unas y otras no te afecta al compilar. Pero internamente si hay diferencia y es que en tiempo de ejecución, la lista se instanciará como Object.

De todas formas, yo te recomiendo instanciarla como ArrayList, así todo queda más claro.

Saludos.

Comment: *la diferencia entre unas y otras no te afecta al compilar* claro que sí afecta. Por ejemplo, las 2 primeras compilan solo usando Java 1.4 o anterior, puesto que generics existe desde Java 5. Además, `List` es una interfaz y `ArrayList` es una de las muchas implementaciones que tiene. Eso marca una gran diferencia.